# How can i pass label text to textview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried every thing I could do to solve the problem because I am newbie I am not getting the clear answer.
This is my first View controller

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"textAdd"]) {

        TextAddViewController *tv=[[TextAddViewController alloc]init];
        if ([self.text isEqualToString:@" "]) {

            tv.usingText.text=@" ";
        }

        else{
        tv.usingText.text=self.text;

        }
    }

    }
-(IBAction)GetttingText:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
{

    TextAddViewController *getText=segue.sourceViewController;
    [self AddTextToCanvasWithGesture:getText.usingText];

}

-(void) LaunchText
{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"textAdd" sender:self];

}

-(void)AddTextToCanvasWithGesture:(UITextView*)takenText
{

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(35, 60,takenText.contentSize.width,takenText.contentSize.height);

    UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    rect.origin.x=0;
    rect.origin.y=0;
    UILabel *textLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];


    [textLabel setText:takenText.text];
     self.text=takenText.text;

    [textLabel setTextColor:takenText.textColor];
    [textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:takenText.font.fontName size:takenText.font.pointSize]];
    [textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [textLabel sizeToFit];
    [holderView setTag:1];
    [textLabel setTag:1+1];
    [holderView addSubview:textLabel];




    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];

    [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
    pinchRecognizer = nil;

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];

    [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
    rotationRecognizer = nil;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];

    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    panRecognizer = nil;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];

    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];



    tapRecognizer = nil;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LaunchText)];

    [doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [doubleTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];


    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
    holderView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


    [tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
}
```

And This Is my Secondview contoller

```
#import "TextAddViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TextAddViewController ()
{

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *noting;


@end

@implementation TextAddViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    ViewController *vm=[[ViewController alloc]init ];
    // [self.noting setText:@"Hi"];
    [self.noting setText:vm.ShowText.text];
    [self.usingText setText:vm.text];

}
```

My code runs perfect for displaying text of textview on Label but i want to edit text of label again so I have to display the text of label in same textview. Problem is it is not showing text in textview. every time textview is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a couple of things wrong. The main thing is that you instantiate a new instance of your `TextAddViewController`. If you are new to object oriented programming this might be a bit difficult to understand (I suggest [following this link (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=introduction%20to%20object%20oriented%20programming) and learning a bit more before continuing on with xcode).

You correctly call the prepareForSegue method, which will fetch the storyboard segue you have created, and tag any data along that seg to your `destinationViewController`. Your problem is that you don't actually fetch your `destinationViewController`. Instead you are creating a new instance of `TextAddViewController` that will just float around in memory doing nothing.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"textAdd"]) {

        TextAddViewController *tv=[[TextAddViewController alloc]init];
        if ([self.text isEqualToString:@" "]) {

            tv.usingText.text=@" ";
        }

        else{
            tv.usingText.text=self.text;

        }
    }
}
```

so instead of this

```
 TextAddViewController *tv=[[TextAddViewController alloc]init];
        if ([self.text isEqualToString:@" "]) {

            tv.usingText.text=@" ";
        }
```

you should be doing this:

```
TextAddViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
[vc setMyObjectHere:object];
```

Where in your case the `object` would be the string you want to set.
This way, you don't need you `GetttingText` IBAction.

I hope this helps you on your way. If you need some clarification feel free to ask. Another suggestion is to keep reading the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:). It might not make sense at the moment, but eventually you will be able to find out stuff like this from the documentation

Comment: @user3763512 Did this solve your problem? If so, could you possibly "tick" this answer?

Comment: Is this correct?-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    ViewController *vm=[[ViewController alloc]init ];
    // [self.noting setText:@"Hi"];
    [self.noting setText:vm.ShowText.text];
    [self.usingText setText:vm.text];

}